# Getting current category with FPC enabled

Tags: php, caching, magento, categories

Is it possible to get current category when Full Page Cache is enabled?
Catalog controller is not executed in this case, so the registry (`current_category` key) is empty. All I can get is the root category

Thanks

Comment: You're going to need to put a lot more information in here. Are you creating your own module? Are you writing a Controller? A Model? A template? Are you overriding anything?

Comment: @jproffit I'm writing a module with random products list block, it's not affected by FPC by implementing hole punching. Need to get current category to fetch this category products. Thinking about getting that info from URL but perhaps there is a better way. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As one of the possible solution is to get category ID by given url. You have table of url rewrites and you have request string.

```
    // Try to get category id directly from request
    if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id')) {
        return Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    }
    // Try to get category id from request by rewrite request path
    $aliases = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getAliases();
    if ($aliases && is_array($aliases) && !empty($aliases) && $aliases['rewrite_request_path']) {
        $urlRewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->loadByRequestPath($aliases['rewrite_request_path']);
        if ($urlRewrite && $urlRewrite->getId()) {
            return $urlRewrite->getCategoryId();
        }
    }
```

May be it's not beautiful solution but it worked well for me.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm not very experienced in Magento rewrites, could you please explain a bit: `url_rewrite` model is not loaded by the code, maybe I'm missing something in my setup? For the first condition in which cases it may work?

Comment: The first condition will work if url rewrite is not applied and request looks like http://yourdomain/catalog/category/view/id/32432/...

Comment: To understand how it works you can try to research file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php

Comment: thanks, will try to debug why it's not loading the model. Url rewrites applied in my case

Comment: xdebugged the problem. It appears there is a need to call setStoreId on `core/url_rewrite` model, then it works perfectly. Cheers

Comment: @azakolyukin You just initialized the whole application, won't that kill FPC performance?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get it via the layer:

```
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
```

Regards,
Kenny

Comment: getCurrentCategory() method works with registry as well, not an option here. Right now I'm getting last category from session $categoryId = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getLastVisitedCategoryId();

Answer (score 0):

You are hole punching your block as indicated here:

> I'm writing a module with random products list block, it's not
>   affected by FPC by implementing hole punching

This means that your block is a stripped down version of Magento (see applyWithoutApp() method), so to access the current_category out of the registry, you'll need to register it in your Container in your hole punch module.